# Can I place two links in bootstrap menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3 for menu links

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a  href="/portal/profile">My profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Competitions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List of profiles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to place two links (My profile and edit) in one line by using bootstrap like showed on picture or any other way to do it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with just CSS, using the nth-child selector. It is still responsive.

```
li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2) {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/z5pXh/3/

Answer (score 1):

nest another ul inside and a little additional css

CSS

```
ul.nav-edit {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.nav-edit li.active {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 88%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-edit">
                <li class="active"><a href="/portal/profile">My profile</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Edit</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Competitions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List of profiles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check out the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Y2LUZ/

Comment: Guys, it doesn't work for all resolutions. If you want responsiveness you can't use it. Check it by dragging the fiddle.

Comment: It will work for responsive you just need to tweak percentage width in your media queries for each viewport

Answer (score 0):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5pXh/2/)

If fixed sizes are good for you, you can use this:

### HTML

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked pos-rel">
        <li class="col-first active"><a  href="/portal/profile">My profile</a></li>
        <li class="col-second"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Competitions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List of profiles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.pos-rel {
    position: relative;
}

.col-first {
    width: 300px;
}

.col-second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 305px;
}
```